# Angular 2 AuthGuard + Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to build an AuthGuard for Angular 2 routes using Firebase Auth.

This is the AuthGuard Service:

```
import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot }    from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService }            from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private AuthService: AuthService, 
                private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.AuthService.loggedIn) { return true; }

    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And this is the AuthService which checks if the user's logged in and binds the result to the property 'loggedIn' in its constructor.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
loggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public af: AngularFire,
    public router: Router) {
        af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            if(user){
                this.loggedIn = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is obviously asynchrony. AuthGuard's canActivate() always returns a false value because the subscription doesn't receive the data in time to change 'loggedIn' to true.

What's the best practice to fix this?

EDIT:

Changed the AuthGuard to return an observable.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.af.auth.map((auth) => {
        if (!auth) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
          return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
  }
```

It kind of works since you don't get redirected to login... But the target AuthGuarded Component is not rendered.

Not sure if it has to do with my app.routes. This is the code for that part:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  ...
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Hi! Can you make a plunkr ?

Comment: @GuillaumeLeMière That would be pretty difficult since there is firebase authentication involved...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Complete the observable using .take(1) to make the component render.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.af.auth.map((auth) => {
        if (!auth) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
          return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).take(1);
  }
```

Comment: It seems after upgrading to Angular 2.0.0 I can no longer use map(). Ts says `Property 'map' does not exist in type 'AngularFireAuth'`.

Comment: I had to add import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' and import 'rxjs/add/operator/take' to make it work, but it works after all. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I should have mentioned the imports, as I had the same issue after upgrading from RC5.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I keep getting the error: `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.` My problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687114/canactivate-doesnt-respond-upon-subscription-change-angular-2-router-angularfir

Comment: I added the required `rxjs` related import statements

Answer (score 10):

For newer versions of `AngularFire`, you have to use `authState` instead:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.authState
      .take(1)
      .map(authState => !!authState)
      .do(auth => !auth ? this.router.navigate(['/login']) : true);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import `take`, `map` and `do` from `rxjs/add/operator`.

Comment: you save my Day :)

Answer (score 0):

Have tested this one with Angular 11 and angular fire 6

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
return this.authService.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  map(authState => !!authState),
  map(auth => {
    if (!auth) {
      this.router.navigate(['/sign-in']);
    }
    return auth;
  }),
 );
}
```

Comment: @mohen dere why do we need two map operators? Can we wrap it into just one?