# canActivate doesn't respond upon subscription change Angular 2 Router AngularFire2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2. This is how I approached my `AuthGuard` service:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) =>  {
      if(auth == null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.allowed = false;
      } else {
        this.allowed = true;
      }
    })
    return this.allowed;
  }
```

The above code works, except when I visit a guarded page directly (i enter URL in browser), it doesn't load the respective component after the subscription resolves to true.

In angular 1, guarding the route was ensuring something resolves first before the route even loads.

It appears in angular 2, the route loads (whether true or false, and doesn't wait for any response from the wire), therefore by the time the subscription value returns as true, I have to go to another route, then come back before it works.

What is the proper way to guard my route to be responsive in Angular 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code `return this.allowed;` is executed before the callback function passed to  `this.af.auth.subscribe(...)` is executed.

It should be like

```
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth.map((auth) =>  {
      if(auth == null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }).first()
  }
```

Comment: Comes back with the error: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.`

Comment: You have to import `map`. Search your error message without `ßAngularDireAuth'`

Comment: Even with that, after importing `map`, I get this error:
`error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the return type of the method. I updated my answer.

Comment: I edited with the imports I had to do. Makes the solution clearer. Thank you for the help

Comment: Thanks for adding the imports.

Answer (score 2):

If you came looking for Angular 4 with angularfire 4, this how I adjusted Gunter's answer:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.af.authState.map((user)=>{
      if(user != null){
        return true;
      }else{
        this._store.dispatch(new LayoutOpenLoginAction());
        return false;
      }
    }).first();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Things are moving so fast it can be hard to keep up.