# Angular 5 canActivate redirecting to login on browser refresh

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase-authentication

Angular 5 authentication app using angularfire2 and firebase.
The app works fine navigating using in-app links e.g. redirect to dashboard after login or link to another page (component) via a button/link in the app.
However, if when on the "http://localhost:4300/dashboard" page I hit the browser refresh (Chrome), it redirects me back to the Login page.
Using BACK / NEXT on the browser works fine - but I guess because I am not specifically asking to go to a particular route.

I have a NavBar that, through use of subscription, identifies whether I am logged in or not (see screenshot top right...) - and this all works fine.

[image: Login page]

I am guessing that on browser refresh or direct URL navigation that it tries to load the page before identifying whether I am already authenticated or not.
The dev console suggests this from the console.log statements I inserted into the nav-bar component and the fact they are "undefined" before Angular core suggests we are running in dev mode:

[image: Developer Tools Console]

**app.routes:**

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './views/profile/profile.component';

import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**auth-gaurd:**

```js
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  status: string;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(state =>
      this.status = state.toString());

    console.log('Can Activate ' + this.authService.authState);
    console.log('Can Activate ' + this.authService.isLoggedIn());
    console.log('Can Activate ' + this.status);

    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**auth.service:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider_Instance } from '@firebase/auth-types';
import { userInfo } from 'os';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;

  public authState = new Subject();

  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { 
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userDetails = user;
        this.authState.next('Logged In');
        //console.log(this.userDetails);
      } else {
        this.userDetails = null;
        this.authState.next('Not Logged In');
      }
    });
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    if (this.userDetails == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**nav-bar.component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  status: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log('Constructor ' + this.status);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe((state) => this.status = state.toString());
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(state =>
      this.status = state.toString());
    console.log('ngOnInit ' + this.status);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added a bit of a fudge to get this working but would welcome a more elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: In each app.route, I added a data: {userUrl:} element to identify what path the User was trying to get to and in the auth.service added a public var to store the directUrl and then set this var in the auth-guard service in canActivate. In auth.service constructor, in the 'if (user)' construct, check whether var is set and navigate if it has a value (after resetting to prevent endless loop!).

Comment: This answer may useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008239/7059557

Answer (score 17):

The `canActivate()` method is called directly on page refresh. So it always returns `false`:

```js
canActivate() {
  this.authService.authState.subscribe(state => {
    this.status = state.toString(); // This is called async/delayed.
  });
  // so method execution proceeds

  // isLoggedIn() returns false since the login stuff in AuthService.constructor
  // is also async:    .subscribe((user) => { /* delayed login */ });
  if(this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
    return true;
  }

  // so it comes here
  this.router.navigate(['/']); // navigating to LoginComponent
  return false;                // and canActivate returns false
}
```

The solution:

```js
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

// ...

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  // when the user is logged in and just navigated to another route...
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; } 

  // proceeds if not loggedIn or F5/page refresh 

  // Store the attempted URL for redirecting later
  this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;

  // go login page
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  return false;
}
```

now, back in the little changed AuthService: (only have changed/relevant code here)

```js
export class AuthService {

  // new
  redirectUrl: string;

  // BehaviorSubjects have an initial value.
  // isLoggedIn is property (not function) now:
  isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  // params declared private and public in constructor become properties of the class
  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    // so this.user is not required since it is reference to this.firebaseAuth
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.loggedIn.next(true);

        // NOW, when the callback from firebase came, and user is logged in,
        // we can navigate to the attempted URL (if exists)
        if(this.redirectUrl) {
          this.router.navigate([this.redirectUrl]);
        }
      } else {
        this.loggedIn.next(false);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**Note:** I have written this code in the answer box and compiled it in my brain. So bugs may exist. Also I don't know if this is actually best practise. But the idea should be clear?!

Based on the [Angular Routing Guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#teach-authguard-to-authenticate)

Seems like there are similar problems/solutions out there: [Angular 2 AuthGuard + Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490533/angular-2-authguard-firebase-auth)

Comment: Thanks. I have recently done something similar and it does work OK. However, I still get a flash of the login page until it determines I have logged in and the REDIRECT kicks in...

Comment: @Woody, I have the same issue I get flash of login page until it determines. How did you solve it?

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo. Sorry but I stalled the project shortly afterwards - work got in the way (sigh)... There is still a flash so if you do succeed, would be great to hear the solution...

Comment: @woody, I have used a library which is https://github.com/serhiisol/ngx-auth. I have implemented the `PrectectedGuad` to all my routes. it was working fine, but when I implemented `Angular universal`. The `ngx-auth` protected guard used to bring the login page for a second and then show the original routes.It used to happen in production. I have removed  (Protected Guard) and implemented my own guard. now it works find.