# How to refresh current page and avoid redirecting to login page angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I am testing this example about login registration in angular
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example)
The problem is that when you are logged in and you refresh the page on browser authguard redirects to login page. I have to fix this and redirect to current page.  Hope anybody can help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Found a similar question answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034663/angular-5-canactivate-redirecting-to-login-on-browser-refresh

Answer (score 1):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
        // authorised so return true
        return true;
    }
    else {
      // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } 
      });
      return false;
    }
 }
```

It's working as of now, i just made the router navigate code to go in `else` part .Check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-registration-login-example-4xgatd)